# Proving (Y,U) be a $T_1$ space.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

This question was asked in my Topology quiz now over and I was unable to solve it.

> Let (X,T) be a $T_1$ space and let (Y,U) be a topological space and let f be a closed map of X onto Y. Prove that (Y,U) is a $T_1$ - space.

Attempt: Let x' and y' be distinct elements in Y. Then there exists x,y in X such that f(x)=x' and f(y)=y' and x$\neq$ y. So, there exists open sets U and V such that x$\in $U and y $\in V$ such that x doesn't lies in V and y doesn't lies in U.

But I am not able to construct open sets in Y which will satisfy $T_1$ property.

Can you please help.

Comment: Hint: $X$ is $T_1$ iff $\forall x \in X: \{x\} \text{ is closed}$. And $f[\{x\}] = \{y\}$ when $f(x)=y$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I took p and q be singletons in Y then I have to prove that Y/{p} and Y/{q} be open by ont , there exists open Sets P and Q , both in X such that f(P) =Y/{p} and f(Q)=Y/{q}. I can now find U and V (disgoint ) such that $P\in U$ and $Q\in V$. But I am not able to prove the required result? Can you please help?

Comment: don’t use open set definitions for $T_1$. Use that it’s equivalent to singletons being closed. Way easier that way.

Comment: You cannot find disjoint neighbourhoods of $p$ and $q$ but you don’t need them either.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, but can you please tell how should I proceed.

Comment: I've told you. Show that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open for any $x$. This follows directly from any definition of $T_1$. So $\{x\}$ is closed etc.